# How to join two table according to a range of ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Say I have two tables

table name: `COSTOMER`

| ID | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Adam | New York |
| 456 | Bob | Paris |
| 789 | Cathy | London |
| 321 | Daniel | Taipei |

table name: `COSTOMER_GROUP`

| upper | lower | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 222 | Gold |
| 223 | 332 | Silver |
| 333 | 747 | Platinum |
| 745 | 999 | Gold |

And the target would be

| ID | Name | City | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Adam | New York | Gold |
| 456 | Bob | Paris | Platinum |
| 789 | Cathy | London | Gold |
| 321 | Daniel | Taipei | Silver |

Each customer belongs to a certain group. And The `COSTOMER_GROUP` table indicates the upper bound and lower upper for each group. For example if ID is between 111 and 222, then the customer belongs to the Gold group. The ID is unique, the interval where each group sits in are non overlapping.

My first thought is to expend `COSTOMER_GROUP` according to the upper and lower bound. Take this as an example, I am thinking of expending the table into a table with 889 entries that looks like the following

| ID | group |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | Gold |
| 112 | Gold |
| 113 | Gold |
| ... |  |
| 222 | Gold |
| 223 | Silver |

And then perform inner join. But I kinda believe there gonna be other better ways doing this. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Basic solution for this is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE COSTOMER (id int, name text, city text);
INSERT INTO COSTOMER (id, name, city)
VALUES 
    (123, 'Adam', 'New York'),
    (456, 'Bob', 'Paris'),
    (789, 'Cathy', 'London'),
    (321, 'Daniel', 'Taipei')
;

CREATE TABLE COSTOMER_GROUP (lower int, upper int, "group" text);
INSERT INTO COSTOMER_GROUP (lower, upper, "group")
VALUES 
    (111, 222, 'Gold'),
    (223, 332, 'Silver'),
    (333, 747, 'Platinum'),
    (745, 999, 'Gold')
;

SELECT COSTOMER.*, COSTOMER_GROUP.group
FROM COSTOMER
JOIN COSTOMER_GROUP ON COSTOMER.id >= COSTOMER_GROUP.lower AND COSTOMER.id <= COSTOMER_GROUP.upper
ORDER BY COSTOMER.id
```

It will output exactly what you want: https://dbfiddle.uk/Ip8CpbxP

**UPD**: You may also want to prevent customer groups from overlapping each other.
Then use Postgres exclusion constraint, see
[8.17.10. Constraints on Ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)

```sql
ALTER TABLE COSTOMER_GROUP ADD CONSTRAINT costomer_group_uniq_range
    EXCLUDE USING gist
    (
        int4range("lower", "upper", '[]') WITH &&   -- this is the crucial
    );
```

You have need btree_gist extension installed for this case.

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```